# Is there a way to get the amount of phones that are connected to the internet and their location?

Tags: android, gps, traffic

I want to make an app that for example, during a football game, is able to display where the most people are. Is there a way that I can do this? I know that traffic apps like Waze have a way to show traffic, can someone point me to resources or give me some tips?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Unless you manage to have all the phones in your own managed network, or make them install your own tracking app.. Of course if you work for some data carrier you can manage to inquiry the local BSS for stat data, but sadly that's information not available to the public...

Comment: How do apps like Waze and Google Maps do it?

Comment: for example, Waze collects data on all the phones it's installed, and share it with their servers which then share the results in a map to other users... it can't collect info of other phones where the app isn't installed, but by the size of users it has, it's significant enough to convince of accurate data...

Answer (score 0):

Everyone would need GPS on and honestly, displaying everyone's exact position is a huge privacy issue. Waze displays a user's "general" location, and it's not real time. it's updated every 2-4 minutes.